# Want to open a tkinter window simultaneously with a matplotlib window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

'''My code opens the matplotlib window and the tkinter but tkinter window opens after quitting the matplotlib window. I want both of them to pop up at the same time.'''

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
import pylab
style.use('seaborn-white')

x = [0,8,-3,-8]
y = [0,8,1,-8]
color=['w','w','w','w']

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

scatter(x,y, s=100 ,marker='.', c=color,edgecolor='w')
plt.ylabel('X')
plt.xlabel('Y')
ax1.yaxis.label.set_rotation(0)
circle1=plt.Circle((0,0),5,color='r',fill=False,linewidth='4')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)
left,right = ax1.get_xlim()
low,high = ax1.get_ylim()
arrow( left, 0, right -left, 0, length_includes_head = True, head_width = 0.15 )
arrow( 0, low, 0, high-low, length_includes_head = True, head_width = 0.15 )


fig = pylab.gcf()
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Inner Slip Ring')


grid()
show()

from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
w=Label(root, text="hello")
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put everything before `show()`:

```
...
root=Tk()
w=Label(root, text="hello")
w.pack()
#root.mainloop()    # Don't use this

grid()
show()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but can you please tell me why not to use  root.mainloop

Comment: If you start the mainloop, your program will stop at that line. It will wait until root is destroyed (when you close the window). mainloop is just an infinite loop that checks for events and you must call it only once in your application (you are doing so with show() ).